# Redux Form Select `invalid` state always true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

I am currently building a `Select` with redux-form and materialUI and it is always returning `invalid`. So I am slightly at a loss.

I would like to have the props passed down to Select have the correct state of the current Select, IE invalid, pristine etc showing correctly.

**Usage of**

```
  <Field
    onUpdate={this.changeAge.bind(this)}
    name={`title`}
    props={{ value: this.props.registration.Title }}
    component={SelectField}
    label={`Title*`}
    validate={[requiredField]}
    options={[{ value: 'mr', text: 'Mr' }, { value: 'mrs', text: 'Mrs' }]}
  />


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    registration: state.registration
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updateKYCItem: bindActionCreators(updateKYCItem, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'RegistrationIntroduction',
    onSubmit,
    onSubmitSuccess
  })(RegistrationIntro)
);
```

[image]

So what is going on here is I am passing the value via the `props` argument as I know no other way to pass the value down as I'm using redux.

**Select Field - Select.js**

```
export default props => {
  console.info(props.meta, props.input);
  let theme = props.meta.valid && props.meta.touched ? textFeild.validTheme : textFeild.defaultTheme;
  const hasError = props.meta.invalid && props.meta.touched && props.value === '';
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FormControl error={hasError}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">{props.label}</InputLabel>
        <Select
          onChange={event =>
            props.onUpdate({
              value: event.target.value,
              field: props.input.name
            })
          }
          value={props.value ? props.value : ''}
          inputProps={{ ...props }}
        >
          {props.options.map(option => (
            <MenuItem selected={props.value === option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.text}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        {hasError &&
          <FormHelperText>{props.meta.error}</FormHelperText>
        }
      </FormControl>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
};

Select.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Why is `validate={[requiredField]}` an array ? the specs says it should be a function https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-validate-value-allvalues-props-name-gt-error-code-optional-

Another way to validate is to pass a `validate` function to the `reduxForm({` options as documented in https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/syncvalidation/

Also to assign values from redux you don't have to use `props` but follow the example using `initialValues` https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/ that takes values from redux

Comment: This is an array of functions, letting you validate multiple rules at once. Interesting idea of using `initialValues`. However with a Select box I need to do this on the fly

Comment: What does `requiredField` look like? I suspect you're not returning errors the way redux-form wants it from there. Also, before rolling your own, I'd highly recommend looking at [redux-form-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form-validators) which lets you do what you're looking for easily and in a highly customizable manner.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import React from 'react';

export const renderDropDownField = (formValues) => {

    const { input, label, meta, options } = formValues;

    const { touched, error } = meta;

    const formcss = touched ? `form-control is-${error && touched ? 'invalid' : 'valid'}`: 'form-control';

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label>
            <select {...input} className={formcss} id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
                {
                    options.map((option) => <option value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>)
                }
            </select>
            {(touched && error) ? <div className="help-block text-danger">{error}</div> : ''}
        </div>
    );
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { renderDropDownField } from "../FormBuilder";

class MyForm extends Component {
    
   onFormSubmit = (formValues) => {
        console.log(formValues)
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        const categories = [
            {
                value: 'none',
                name: 'Select Category'
            },
            {
                value: 'miss',
                name: 'Miscellaneous'
            },
        ];
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)} className="needs-validation px-5">
                    <Field name="categorie" options={categories} component={renderDropDownField} />
                    <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary'>Save Changes</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const validate = (formValues) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!formValues.categorie || 'none' === formValues.categorie) {
        errors.categorie = "Please select a valid categorie.";
    }
    return errors;
}


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'blogEditForm',
    validate
})(MyForm);
```